# Add elements in nested document then retrieve the _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following collection definition:

```
// Includes
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create required sub schemas
const subSchema0 = new Schema({
   value: String,
});

const subSchema = new Schema({
  idWordsLibraryName: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'WordsLibrary1_0',
  },

  type: String,
  values: [
    subSchema0,
  ],
});

const schema = new Schema({
  version_: String,

  idWordsLibraryName: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'WordsLibrary1_0',
  },

  idsDads: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'LocationStructure1_0',
  }],

  params: [
    subSchema,
  ],
});
```

Summary -> One document with nested parameters with nested values.

I have the following request that add some values into a particular parameter

```
this.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: data.idLocationStructure,

  'params._id': data.idLocationStructureParameter,
}, {
  $push: {
    'params.$.values': {
      $each: dataToPush,
    },
  },
}, {
  new: true,
});
```

It works as expected.

What I want now is to get the _id of pushed elements, but without loading all values of the parameter.

I have tried to use the `select` option of findOneAndUpdate but it don't work using the projection:

```
this.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: data.idLocationStructure,

  'params._id': data.idLocationStructureParameter,
}, {
  $push: {
    'params.$.values': {
      $each: dataToPush,
    },
  },
}, {
  new: true,

  select: {
    'params.$.values': 1,
  },
});
```

It gets me:

```
{
  "_id": "57273904135f829c3b0739dd",

  "params": [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
  ],
},
```

I have tried to perform a second request to get the _ids as well, but it don't work either:

```
this.find({
  _id: data.idLocationStructure,

  'params._id': data.idLocationStructureParameter,
}, {
  _id: 1,

  'params.$.values': {
    $slice: -nbAdded,
  },
});
```

If you have any idea of how retrieving the `_id` of the pushed values without loading all values of the parameter, you are very welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after tons of researches all over the web and stack overflow <3 I have found a solution, which is:

```
this.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data.idLocationStructure),
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$params',
  }, {
    $match: {
      'params._id': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data.idLocationStructureParameter),
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$params.values',
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      'params.values._id': -1
    },
  },
  {
    $limit: nbAdded,
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: '$params.values._id',
    },
  },
]);
```

If you experience the same problem, here is the explaination:

- `$match` makes me taking the good high level document
- `$unwind` makes me to go into the params array in the document we `$match`
- `$match` makes me taking the good parameter
- `$unwind` makes me to go into the values array
- I `$sort` all values by `_id` DESC
- I `$limit` to the number of values I added previsoulsy
- I change the name of the `_id` *(like an alias)*

So I got as result an array that contains the last added values `_ids`